# iOS Sandbox testing vs. production

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox

I am creating my first iOS app with consumable products. The account, products and version are all set. The status of my app in iTunes Connect is `Prepare for Upload` and the status of my products is: `Ready to Submit`.

Is it true that whether I am testing or pushing to production, I have to do `submit binary`, right? And `submit to binary` would eventually become `ready for sale`?
Since I still need to test my app, how would I tell iTunesConnect to hold pushing it to production until I am done with testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit your binary, you will have the option to either release it automatically after approval, or to hold it; if you hold it, you can either manually release it when you're ready, or set a specific date for releasing.

All of this is covered in the [iTunes Connect Developers Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

If the status is `Prepare to Upload`, then iTunes Connect won't *push* you to production. You can upload your binary, and then, enter/update the metadata, such as description, app icons, etc. and then release it whenever you want. You have full control over when you want to publish your app to the Store.

See the screenshot below from [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html) and also read the rest of that section and the table from the link.

[image]

Comment: yes I saw those statuses. My primary task was to test and at the same time make sure not to push code all the way to apple store.I already marked Jason's comment as the answer... thank you!

Comment: @user1019042 "I already marked the first answer that came as accepted" is not a right approach in Stack Overflow. You can change the accepted answer any time; however it's a good idea to wait for a while before deciding, since people are taking time to read your question and provide a helpful answer to that. You definitely do have the right to pick which ever answer that was the most helpful. In this case I was taking screenshots and so on before posting my answer and after posting I noticed there's already another answer with less detail and just a link. Good luck. (: